# Proving Function Space as vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I was doing some vector space questions and stumbled upon a question with a solution provided.

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ea6PR.png)

I did not understand the need to substitute the functions of $f(3)$ with $f(1)$ as they don't serve any purpose in proving the vector subspace.

Comment: It is part of showing that the subspace is closed under addition.

Comment: There's no solution in the attached picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $W$ is a subspace of $V$, we have to show that it is closed under addition of elements (we have to show we cant add elements of a subspace to get out of our subspace; our subspace is closed.

First, it shows that it is indeed a subspace by showing that it contains the zero vector as $0(x)=0$ so $0(3)=0(1)$.

Now we have to show that it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. So given two functions in $W$(call them $A$ and $B$, we have to show that $A+B$ is in $W$ and multiplying them by scalars also results in a function in $W$. So your source goes from $3$ to $1$ and shows they map to the same element so that it lies in $W$. To do so, it uses the fact that your individual functions have that property.

So:

$f+g$ is in $W$ if $(f+g)(3)=(f+g)(1)$. to show this, your source breaks it down into individual functions. So $(f+g)(3)=f(3)+g(3)=f(1)+g(3)=f(1)+g(1)=(f+g)(1)$

for scalar multiplication (any scalar $c$):
$cf(3)=cf(1)$

your link clutters everything up by showing everything at once. Remember that our vectors are actully functions not the real numbers we plug into them

Comment: It still just maps to a function and that too for a definitive value of 3. What about the other cases when x != 3 ? , Does it still hold true for it ?

Comment: we don't care for the other values of $f$.

Comment: Ah, alright thanks a lot

Comment: $f$ can map five to six or seven to nine. It would still be in $W$ as the only requirement for it is to be $f(3)=f(1)$

Comment: Different elements in $W$, can map different numbers to different numbers. Given $g$, $f$ and $h$ in $W$, we only care that their sum and scalar result in a function $t$ that follows $t(3)=t(1)$. $t$ has no other restriction. therefore, we only check to see if $t(3)=t(1)$ as if that holds, $t$ is in $W$ and so our subspace is closed.